# Why does archive manager extract files out of folders?

Tags: files, filemanager, archive

There are a lot of archives I'm trying to extract, but when i extract a folder with files in it or a folder with many folders and files in it, all the files are extracted out of the folders. How do i fix this?

Answer (score 2):

If you right click the archive and choose *Extract here*, you should get the behavior you want by default.

But perhaps you want to examine the contents first and are opening the archive with `archive manager` and then using the *Extract* button.

In that case, make sure that under `Actions` in the extract dialog the checkbox `Keep directory structure` is checked.